# Recursively style a css class for an unknown number of depths

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, sass

Basically i have a dropdown and in that dropdown it can have either items or another dropdown. In the sub-dropdown it can have the same: either items or another dropdown and this can go on for an x amount of times.

I'm trying to update the state of an icon so that when the dropdown is clicked, the arrow changes to a down state (V) to show the expanded state, and when it is closed the arrow changes back to horizontal state (>) to show the closed state.

Here is the code i have now, but this only works for two layers of depth, and i need it to work for an N number of depths:

```
.subsection .expandable .header_icon {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.subsection .expandable--open .header_icon{
    transform: none;
}

.subsection .subsection .expandable .header_icon {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.subsection .subsection .expandable--open .header_icon{
    transform: none;
}
```

As expected, it only goes down to two layers as it is hard coded, but I need it to work for an unknown X amount of layers.. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Include a sample of your HTML showing different levels of depth in your dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do this, css will apply styles to as many elements as you have with these classes:

```
.subsection .expandable .header_icon {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.subsection .expandable--open .header_icon{
    transform: none;
}
```

edit: the only two classes that matter here are `expandable` and `expandable--open`. as long as those are on any n number of nested elements, they'll display their icon appropriately.

Comment: I tried doing so, but now only the first dropdown follows these rules and now each sub-dropdown doesn't apply the styles..

Context: for a dropdown in the 3rd level the class flow would be something like: 
.section .expandable .subsection .section .expandable .subsection .section .expandable

Comment: This is because you’re being too specific with your css selectors. Make classes with the two classes I listed above, with no additional selectors.